# Samsung Galaxy Tab - Softkeyboard makes the controls overlapping each other

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, overlapping

I have a peculiar problem with Samsung Galaxy Tab GT-P7500 (with Android 3.1)
When I clicked on any of the editable control in my web page, soft keyboard comes and its disturbs the alignment & make the controls in the page to overlap.

Similar problem also occurs, even without keyboard, in the landscape orientation.

Is anyone have similar problem and have pointers to fix this problem

Thanks in advance

Comment: Define `layout_height="wrap_content"` not use "match_parent" in root View in your xml file will solve this `overlap on EditText` problem.